# Scipy.Optimize.Curve_Fit Not Fitting Cos^2 Well

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to fit a curve of the form

acos^2(x+b)+c

using scipy's curve_fit routine but I have not been able to get it to find good parameters. The fit doesn't seem to find the right amplitude or period.

I've tried modifying the fit function and changing the initial guesses to math the data. Below is the fit function and the fitting routine.

```
def fit(x, a, phi, b):
    return (a*abs(math.cos(x+phi)**2))+b

#Vectorizing fit function to accept list input
fit_v = np.vectorize(fit)

params1, covs1 = optimize.curve_fit(fit_v, data_1_x_calibrated, data_1_y, p0=[20,30,90])
```

The data is plotted using the following code

```
#Plotting Fit 1
fit_1_y_data = []
for i in range(len(data_1_x)):
    fit_1_y_data.append(params1[0]*math.cos(data_1_x_calibrated[i]+params1[1])**2+params1[2])
plt.plot(data_1_x_calibrated, fit_1_y_data, label="Fit")
plt.plot(data_1_x_calibrated, data_1_y, "r", label = "Data")
plt.legend()
```

The result is the following: Data and Fit Plot

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't seem to fit for a period: only for an offset `b`, amplitude `a` and phase `phi`. That is unlikely to yield a good fit in only the rarest of cases.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to take the absolute when you're already squaring the function: cos^2 will always be positive, so abs(cos^2)) is redundant.